# If the sum of 5 natural numbers is 50, find the probability that the 5 numbers are even.

Tags: probability

To find the sample space:

$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 50$$

Number of solutions (natural numbers) = $54 \choose 4$

To find favourable outcomes:
The numbers have to be even so I assumed them to be $2(y_1), 2(y_2), \ldots 2(y_5)$

$$2(y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5) = 50$$

$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 25$$

Number of solutions = $29 \choose 4$

The answer I'm getting is $\frac{203}{2703}$. But the answer should be $\frac{33}{658}$.

Is the approach right or am I missing something?

Comment: The answer assumes natural numbers do not contain $0$ while your answer assumes $0$ contained. Your approach is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an equation

$a_1+a_2+...+a_k=n$

The formula for number of non-negative integer solutions is ${n+k-1\choose k-1}$.

The formula for number of positive integer solutions is ${n-1\choose k-1}$.

The answer uses the second formula: ${24\choose4}\over{49\choose4}$$=$$33\over658$.

Answer (score 0):

I think the add is just put a $+$ in $1,1,1,1,1,1$, so, put 4 plus in 50 "1"s is $49\times 48\times 47\times 46$, and all even means put 4 plus in 25 "2"s is $24\times 23 \times 22\times 21$, and that is $33 / 658$